# Definitive and immediate way to export a path

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Assume I want to export a path, let's say `FOOBAR` and make the changes not only effective immediately and everywhere but also permanent. My goal is to have a list of commands that can be entered manually in an active shell session as well as executed from within a shell script (which in turn might be executed via the shell or a GUI file manager etc.).

Old processes don't need to be aware of any changes.

Here's what I want to happen to `FOOBAR`:

- Add a new value without overwriting previous values.
- Make the change accessible system-wide (for any program or shell session, no matter how it is launched) within the current user context.
- Make the change effective immediately (i.e. no logout required etc.)

My current approach is exporting the value as a set-command to both `.profile` and `.bashrc`:

```
echo "export FOOBAR=$FOOBAR:$HOME/example/" >> $HOME/.profile;
echo "export FOOBAR=$FOOBAR:$HOME/example/" >> $HOME/.bashrc;
source $HOME/.profile;
```

How can this be improved in terms of:

- It does work, but are there cases where this will fail and how can I avoid them (i.e. are there any common processes or actions a ubuntu user will make etc. that will break my exported path)?
- Are there any security concerns to this approach and how can those be fixed?
- Are there any other collisions or negative consequences I have to pay attention to, in order to make this as universal as possible (within the ubuntu family)?

Comment: Couple of points you should address. 1) "Make the change accessible system-wide" . System wide changes for any user or just yourself ? From your example you are doing only for yourself. System-wide changes are done in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`. 2)  " but are there cases where this will fail" . Which cases are we talking about ? Don't make people guess. Define your requirements clearly  3) " no logout required" part might not quite work for GUI, as gui sessions source `~/.profile` on each login only once as far as i know, so they need to be restarted for change to take place

Comment: Another thing. Here you are using `FOOBAR` as variable. So that's a path variable used by another ( external ) command ?  because there exists `$PATH` variable , which is used by every shell and many programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it should be either `~/.profile` or `.bashrc`. Not both since `/.bashrc` is loaded -from- `~/.profile`.
- A non-login shell will only load `~/.bashrc` and not `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` so if that is a concern `~/.profile` is not going to be used.
- a non-login with no shell will load the configuration set at `$BASH_ENV`. Have not found what is loads but `~/.bashrc` should be one of them.

Regarding your 1st bullet point:

- That is probably not a good idea. And probably not how it works. When you reload environment variables they will start from empty (assuming you meant it should not empty on reloading them ;-) ).

Regarding your 2nd bullet point:

- if you want it for all users use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`. [/etc/environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) is the correct place for system wide environment variables. And also: this rules out `~/.profile`.

Regarding your 3rd bullet point:

`/etc/environment` does not require a reboot. It requires a re-login. And it should be done with a re-login; you can source it again but that only applies to your session and what is started after you sourced it. Not for already running processes.

Nevertheless

```
. /etc/environment
```

is a method to reload all variables. But again: this does not reset them for currently running processes. Only for the current shell and newly started processes.

Regarding 4th, 5th, 6th bullet point:

Only problem I can see is it could run wild. If you add it to `~/.bashrc` and source that 10, 20 times your variable is going to get flooded with the same parts.

And no and no. No security risks.

Comment: Your link also mentions `~/.pam_environment` as an user-based alternative to `/etc/environment`. If I create an assignment there (for example `FOOBAR=/home/@{PAM_USER}/example/`) it should be enough to satisfy my requirements. You mentioned that `. /etc/environment` can be used to reload paths for new processes (which is what I need). Is there an equivalent way of initializing the new values without a re-login for the PAM file?

Comment: @mınxomaτ: Sounds like you should use `~/.profile` after all, which you can source anytime using `. ~/.profile`. Apparently you don't need it to be accessible to other users.

Comment: Not if he wants it system wide. And @mınxomaτ you can only reload for current shell and new processes. Older processes will keep the old values unless you restart them all manually (or login again ;-) )

Comment: @Rinzwind: The OP's definition of system wide was: "for any program or shell session, no matter how it is launched". And he is considering `~/.pam_environment`.

Comment: System wide was a bad choice of words. I meant system wide as in "accessible for any program", but within the current user context. I will clarify that in my question. Still, from the recommendations in the ubuntu help page linked by @Rinzwind, the PAM file sounds like the recommended file (over `.profile` that is)?

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't require old processes to know that path.

Comment: @mınxomaτ: I edited [that section in EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables). ;) And it's not recommended over `~/.profile`, it's one of two recommended files.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the clarification. The note says that assignments in profile can override the previously set PAM values, so I'll use .profile.

Comment: The advantage of /etc/environment method over others is with servers (and I consider it a better practice to use that over others just because you will do it correctly when using a server ;-) ). Use ~./profile if that fits your needs ;-) Or pam_environment. It is after all your system :D

Comment: But `/etc/environment` doesn't expand variables, and the syntax for variable expansion in `~/.pam_environment` is not understood by e.g. bash. None of them is a true script file.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson there is a reason to recommend `.pam_environment` over `.profile`. Something as simple as `ssh host foo` will be affected by the former, but not necessarily by the latter.

Comment: @muru: Can't see a reason to state that one is generally better than the other. One is intended to be read by PAM, the other is a script file. Which is best ought to depend on the context.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson if the objective is to affect programs or shell sessions, no matter how they are launched, then one is objectively better than the other for reasons given.

Comment: @muru: The reasons given also include a desire to expand variables. (I assume it's actually about adding a directory to PATH.) And to make the change effective within the session.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson sigh. I think I have pointed this out to you before, but `pam_env` can expand variables just fine. It just has unusual syntax. And even changes to `.profile` can't be effected in a desktop session, so that's a tie for me.

Comment: @muru: I was talking about the combination of variable expansion in the file and sourcing that very file to make the new value of an environment variable available to new processes within the current session. Please see previous discussion above. I know that pam_env can handle variable expansion in `~/.pam_environment`, but AFAIK it does not handle it if you would try to do it in `/etc/environment`. Would appreciate a correction (and a working example) if I'm wrong as regards `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, expansions don't work in `/etc/environment`, but a system-wide setting can be done in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, where expansion does take place.

Comment: Thanks, @muru! Didn't even know that such a file existed. ;)